# Application.ThreadException event for ALL GUI threads

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have a WinForms application that creates a multiple forms, each in their own GUI thread, (not the main  GUI thread). I would like to handle the Unhandled Exception event (Application.ThreadException) for all these forms to handle any errors. I would also like to handle exceptions from worker threads - this bit seems to be working correctly, but I'm having trouble with exceptions from GUI threads still:

Program.cs:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  AttachExceptionHandlers();
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
public static void AttachExceptionHandlers()
{
  Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
  Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);      
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDispatcher_UnhandledException);
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
//GUI Thread Crash
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  object a = null;
  a.ToString();
}
//Worker Thread Crash
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Thread myThread = new Thread(() => 
  { 
    object a = null; 
    a.ToString(); 
  });
  myThread.Start();
  myThread.Join();
}
//New Thread, New Gui Crash
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Thread myThread = new Thread(() => 
  { 
    using (CrashingForm form = new CrashingForm()) //Crashing Form Crashes in it's FormLoad event.
    {
      Application.Run(form);
    }
  });
  myThread.Start();
  myThread.Join();
}
```

This code will call my exception handler in the first 2 instances (GUI Thread Crash and Worker Thread Crash) but does not handle the third instance where a new GUI thread is created. I have found that if I call Program.AttachExceptionHandlers(); before the Application.Run(form) line, all is OK, but this is undesirable as I would have to implement some logic to make sure the call to Program.AttachExceptionHandlers() is made before we call a form is created on each thread (the call to Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode fails if called after creating a form on the thread).

This example is part of a bigger bit of code which would ideally give the user of my code a simple API to call at the start of their application (like in Program.cs) to attach exception handlers. The exception handler then does some magic to record details about the exception being thrown before the application dies. So telling the user they have to track down each time they create a new GUI thread (worker threads don't seem to be effected by this issue) and reattach the Application.ThreadException Handler is not such a clean solution.

Is there another way to achieve this, without having to re registerer for the Application.ThreadException event each time a new GUI thread is created?

Comment: You have no idea what you are getting yourself into.  Complaining about a single method call is very silly, given the enormous amount of work you'll have to do to create a multi-threaded GUI that does not [random deadlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  Don't do it.

Comment: OK fair point. What's not clear from my question is that I'm just actually just providing a simple library that gets included in other applications to handle unhandled exceptions. Because of this I don't really have any control over the number of GUI threads created in the target application or any other nuts things the users of my library will do. Because of this I don't want to force them into making an extra call each time they create a new GUI thread. The link above seems to explain about message pumps etc. Each GUI Thread has their own message pump, so this deadlocking is not an issue.

Comment: "a WinForms application that creates a multiple forms, each in their own GUI thread" -- there's your problem right there. As far as "I don't want to force them into making an extra call each time they create a new GUI thread" goes, you are being way too accommodating for your clients.  If you can solve the problem simply by forcing them to make an extra call for each new UI thread, do it. Don't waste any of _your_ time bending over backwards to make life easier for someone abusing the framework.

Comment: @HansPassant In the time where even one's mobile phone has multiple cores I think it is reasonable to have multiple threads and message pumps in a GUI.  Though I agree that you shouldn't use multiple message pumps unless you have a compelling reason.

Comment: All that a user interface thread needs to do is keep human eyes occupied and stay responsive to human hands.  Which are very undemanding, human time ticks 7 orders of magnitude slower than processor time.  If you cannot do this with a single processor core then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant I have a similar solution with multiple GUI threads and it works well as long as one is careful to marshal add/remove/update to the underlying data structures on the UI thread and offload all non UI logic to worker threads. I have two similar apps one with multi-threaded and the other with a single UI thread. The multi-threaded version is more responsive(slowness in one view doesn't affect another) and it makes a big difference as the user could have 20 to 50 views(grids) open. It takes extra effort, but worth it in my opinion and developers should'nt be afraid to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another way to achieve this, without having to re registerer
>   for the Application.ThreadException event each time a new GUI thread
>   is created?

I'm not aware of any, and my teammate and I have spent a good amount of time looking into it.  .NET WinForms doesn't appear to be very opinionated when it comes to how to create / manage / destroy multiple message pumps.

We use framework methods similar to the one below, in addition to [Retlang's](http://code.google.com/p/retlang/) WinFormsFiber.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        CreateFormAndStartMessagePump(() => CreateForm("first"), OnException, OnException, false, "pumpThread1");
        CreateFormAndStartMessagePump(() => CreateForm("second"), OnException, OnException, false, "pumpThread2");
        // note app shutdown not handled here
    }

    private static T CreateFormAndStartMessagePump<T>(
        Func<T> createForm,
        ThreadExceptionEventHandler onThreadException,
        UnhandledExceptionEventHandler onDomainException,
        bool isBackground,
        string name) where T : Form
    {
        var latch = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        T form = null;
        var thread = new Thread(ts =>
        {
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
            Application.ThreadException += onThreadException;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += onDomainException;
            form = createForm();
            latch.Set();
            Application.Run();
        })
        {
            IsBackground = isBackground,
            Name = name
        };
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        latch.WaitOne();
        return form;
    }

    private static Form CreateForm(string name)
    {
        var form = new Form();
        form.Text = name;
        form.Show();
        return form;
    }

    private static void OnException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private static void OnException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```